# What's the standard to make an event that doesn't pass any information along?

Tags: c#, events

I've got an event that literally just lets the user know something happened. They have to manually take action for that event, as no data is passed from it.

However, I'm not sure what would be more idiomatic:

```
public event Action MyEvent;
//clearly says no arguments
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
//uses the EventHandler class to no effect, but might be more idiomatic.
public event Action<object> MyEvent;
//just like the first but passes the sender if needed.
```

Which would be the standard way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

The idiomatic approach would be to just use `EventHandler`. Pass in an appropriate sender if you have one or `null` otherwise, and `EventArgs.Empty`.

I know it's somewhat crazy, but that's the convention. Bear in mind that plain `EventArgs` has no useful information in it, so *any* `EventHandler`-based event is basically saying "I may get a sender, but that's probably all."

However, with delegate variance as of C# 2, there is a benefit to this: you can use the same event handling method for *all* events which follow the convention... so you can have (say) logging event handlers which use reflection to dump whatever information they *are* given in the `EventArgs`, even if they don't know about it at compile-time.

It's not the greatest argument in the world for a convention, admittedly - but it's a reasonably strong one. Of course [routed events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) are slightly different in how they're subscribed, but even so the delegates follow the same pattern.

Comment: There is also another benefit: write a `handleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)` handler now that ignores `e`, and it will continue to work if the event type is changed from `EventHandler` to `EventHandler<MySuperDuperEventArgs>` later. This is similar to what you describe, but a benefit for the person maintaining the class that declares and raises the event, rather than for the person using it.